# Retrieve records based on Date

Tags: mysql

I have a date column in my table.
Is there any way in mysql to retrieve record based on date excluding the time part?

I have tried appending * but does not seems to work.

`SELECT * FROM myTable where filterDate="2010-08-01 *"`

Is there any way to do it like this rather then filtering it by using `between`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where filterDate LIKE "%2010-08-01 %"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function of mysql

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where DATE_FORMAT(filterDate,'%Y-%m-%d') ="2010-08-01"
```

Comment: I am not able to filter record this way.

Comment: @user549757: This is a standard way in mysql. you may did something wrong. Try it again as it is in answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(filterDate , '%d-%m-%Y') AS new_date FROM table_name WHERE
DATE_FORMAT(filterDate , '%d-%m-%Y') = '2010-08-01'
```